# Multiprocessing forks using multiple functions

Tags: c, fork

Im having a bit of trouble trying to wrap my head around forking if the parent needs to execute more than one function in two sets of child processes.

This code would execute function() n-times

```
pid_t = pid;
int n; /* number of child processes*/

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) 
    {
        if ((pid = fork()) < 0) 
        {
        /*error handling*/
        }
        else if (pid == 0) 
        {
            function();
            exit(0);
        }
    }
/*Parent waits*/
```

How do I concurrently execute another function with another set of child process that comes from the parent.

1) parent forks n process all executing function1()

2) parent also forks m other process executing function2()

3) Both sets of children execute while the parent then waits all sets of process are completed.

Comment: Two loops after each other, one forking for `function1` and the other forking for `function2`?

Comment: Or a local variable incremented on each loop, when even cal `function1` when odd `function2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind all of the processes for `function1` getting `fork`'d before any of of the processes for `function2` you can just use to consecutive loops:

```
pid_t pid;
int n, m;

// Create n processes running function1
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (fork() == 0) {
        function1();
        exit();
    }
}

// Create m processes to run function2
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    if (fork() == 0) {
        function2();
        exit();
    }
}

// Parent waits
```

But this does not scale if you want to run `n` different functions.

---

A scalable answer would be to use an array of function pointers combined with an array containing the counts of how many times each function should be run.

```
#define LEN 3

void func1();
void func2();
void func3();

/* f is an array of pointers to each function */
void  (*f[LEN])() = {func1, func2, func3};
/* count contains the number of times each function should be called */
int count[LEN]    = {  1  ,   2  ,   3  };

for (int i = 0; i < LEN; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < counts[i]; j++) {
         if (fork() == 0) {
             f[i](); // Call function
             exit();
         }
    }
}
```

I left out things like error checking but the general idea is to loop over an array of functions and fork the desired number of times for each function.